# Reviews are not updating

Tags: bug

On my Review queue, I can see this:
[image]

But when I click on ["Low Quality Posts"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) I am told that `There are no items for you to review`. This is fine, I understand that, sometimes, all the reviews were taken by the time I got to the particular item. HOWEVER, if I click again on "review" the same counters (and images) will be shown.

Which means, the page with the summary of reviews is not being refreshed.