# Reviewing tasks dashboard bug

Tags: feature-request, bug

All the time I see, on the reviewing tasks, lot of posts to review. When I choose one type of them by clicking on it, I see no posts are available. And when I click back, I see there are

As this example shows:

[image]

After clicking:

[image]

That is annoying.
There are improvements that should be done around this.

Comment: And [/review seems stuck with stale numbers today](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266066), and [First Posts Queue not empty, but I have nothing to review](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266069) and [Reviews are not updating](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266081), etc.